# Windows 10 Kiosk Mode and msg.exe

Tags: windows-10, kiosk

We implemented Kiosk mode on a couple PCs and are now unable to send the PC a message using msg.exe. The msg.exe works when the PC is not in Kiosk mode.

This is what we did to implement Kiosk Mode:

1. Configure Shell Launcher
   a.  Turn on Shell Launcher
   b.  Set Custom Shell application (Application called Symmetry)
2. Other Settings
   a.  Put Workstation in Tablet Mode
   b.  Hide Ease of Access button
   c.  Disable hardware power button on computer
   d.  Remove power button from sign-in screen
   e.  Disable removable media

I am pretty sure some of this was accomplished via powershell

We have a windows 2012 R2 sever that will send a message to a PC using the msg command using the following format:

MSG * /SERVER:ComputerName /TIME:10 "Message to be sent"

This message is sent correctly when the PC is not in Kiosk Mode, but when the PC is in Kiosk mode the message is never received.

I am worried that the PC cannot receive the message while in Kiosk mode.

Please help! We need this functionality. Thanks!

Comment: Any answer to this question in its present form can only be a guess. You need more detail.

Comment: Tried to add more detail, but I am not sure what you are looking for.  It simply works when the PC is not in Kiosk mode but does not work when it is in Kiosk mode.

Comment: David - Let's start with `Kiosk Mode` This is your machine and we know "nothing" about it so explain it to us with great detail like we're all school kids learning. There is not a diagnostic button we can press on this side to give us verbose detail about your problem. You must convey to us with great detail to ensure you get the best and most accurate help you need and deserve to get for your problem. We are here to help but we cannot explain your system, environment, software, code, etc. unless you explain with detail and specificity.

Comment: Kiosk mode from PC setting, Kiosk mode from 3rd party software, I mean we do not want to assume anything otherwise it is just a guess for us.

Comment: Does any of the more detail help?

Comment: Which Kiosk software?  Windows 10 supports and has its own Kiosk mode of your usin that that would explain why the program isn't working as for third-party you have to configure the third-party solution to allow the program in question